# How can I prevent 't-out' from escaping my Html code?

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-16

How can I prevent `t-out` from escaping my Html code?

I am trying to display an Html code on my Website. In older Odoo versions I used `t-raw` and it worked fine. Now in Odoo 16 `t-raw` is deprecated and `t-out` is the way to go. But `t-out` always escapes my code and displays it as text on my website.

This is my old code with `t-raw`:

```
<div class="row">
    ​<t t-raw="html_output"/>
</div>
```

Here is my new code with `t-out`:

```
<div class="row">
    ​<t t-out="html_output"/>
</div>
```

[image: This is what it should look like]

[image: And this is what it's showing]

How can I stop `t-out` from escaping my Html code?

Answer (score 1):

Per [Odoo 16 QWeb Templates: Advanced Markup](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/frontend/qweb.html?highlight=markup#advanced-output),

> By default, `out` should HTML-escape content which needs to be escaped, protecting the system against XSS

There are a number of examples in the documentation, but I don't have quite enough context from your question to know exactly which one applies, so I'll take a couple guesses.

Python: If your `html_output` variable is not fields.Html, then you should change it to one in your model.

```
html_output = fields.Html()
```

JavaScript: If your `html_output` variable is created in the browser, then you should wrap it in Markup.

```
const { Markup } = require("web.utils");

// ...in some method prior to rendering
html_output = Markup(html_output);
```